# How to get average hourly number of entries?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame `df` and I want to calculate the average hourly number of entries per day, grouped by runway

```
year   month   day   hour    runway
2017   12      30    10      32L
2017   12      30    11      32L
2017   12      30    11      32L
2017   12      30    11      32L
2017   12      30    11      30R
2018   12      31    10      32L
2018   12      31    10      32L
2018   12      31    11      32L
2018   12      31    11      32L
```

The expected result is this one:

```
hour   avg. count per hour
10     1.5    
11     3
```

If I group by `hour` and do `size`, I get the total count of entries per hour. But how can I get the average number of entries per hour?

```
df.groupby("hour").size()
```

I tried something like this, but it fails with the error:

```
s = df.groupby(["hour"])["month","day"].nunique()
df_arr = asma_df.groupby(["hour"]).size().reset_index()
df_arr[0]/df_arr["hour"].map(s)
```

**UPDATE:**

The indicated duplicate question is different from mine. I am asking about the **average** hourly count, not the total hourly count. Therefore it is not helpful.

Comment: Please delete the link to another question. It is different from mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need assign to new column `avg` output of `division`, what is `Series`:

```
s = df.groupby(["hour"])["day"].nunique()
df_arr = df.groupby(["hour"]).size().reset_index(name='avg')
df_arr['avg'] /= df_arr["hour"].map(s)
#alternative
#df_arr = df_arr.assign(avg = df_arr['avg'] / df_arr["hour"].map(s))
print (df_arr)
   hour  avg
0    10  1.5
1    11  3.0
```

Or divide `Series` and last creare `DataFrame` by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
g = df.groupby(["hour"])["day"]
df_arr = g.size().div(g.nunique()).reset_index(name='avg')
print (df_arr)
   hour  avg
0    10  1.5
1    11  3.0
```

And solution for check values for `mean`:

```
df_arr = df.groupby(["hour"])["day"].agg(['size','nunique'])
df_arr['avg'] = df_arr['size'] / df_arr['nunique']
print (df_arr)
      size  nunique  avg
hour                    
10       3        2  1.5
11       6        2  3.0
```

Comment: If I do `df_arr = df_arr['avg'] / df_arr["hour"].map(s)`, I get the DataFrame without column names. I tried `df_arr.columns = ["hour","avg"]`, but again the same issue.

Comment: @ScalaBoy - You get `Series`, not `DataFrame`. Need `df_arr['avg'] = df_arr['avg'] / df_arr["hour"].map(s)` what is in same like `df_arr['avg'] /= df_arr["hour"].map(s)`